# 301 redirect with htaccess issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, tumblr

I have today a blog at Tubmlr, and my domain is like this: blog.example.com. And URL to a post in my blog would be like this blog.example.com/post/34545435345/some-title-etc

Now I have moved all my content to a hosted Wordpress, and my domain is www.example.com. The posts from Tumblr in Wordpress now got a URL like this: www.exampe.com?p=34545435345

I want to set up a .htaccess to 301 redirect from my old subdomain to my new blog.  I have tried this rule in the .htaccess -file, but it seems not to work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?posts/([0-9]+).*$ http://www.example.com/$1
```

Answer (score 1):

To all others who got the same issue, here is my solution:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?post/([0-9]+).*$ http://www.example.com/?p=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's just due to inconsistencies in your example and your RewriteRule: your rule has /posts/ instead of /post, and your destination is missing the "?p=". You should also add the R=301 flag. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?post/([0-9]+).*$ http://www.example.com/?p=$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Sorry for the typos in my example. I tried your example, and it didn't work either.

Comment: What error are you getting? Is it a 404, or infinite redirect? Try using RewriteLog & RewriteLogLevel to debug: http://www.latenightpc.com/blog/archives/2007/09/05/a-couple-ways-to-debug-mod_rewrite

Comment: I changed [R=301] to [R=301,L] and then it worked :) Thanks for your help!